# IN Magento, how can I replicate the creation of a URL rewrite across multiple stores?

Tags: magento, url-rewriting

This is my thinking so far:

Create Custom module which is fired by an event listener when Admin Magento Website triggers event:

> controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_urlrewrite_save

So far so good...

QUESTION 1
How do I get the methods from the observer class which relate to the data I need to be able to replicate this request across every active store?

QUESTION 2
I realise I will need a Helper class to fetch all the websites which need to be 
As a secondary question is there a magento class/function which fetches list of websites in an install?

QUESTION 3 
Apart from adding logic to check if the chosen product/category has an associated product/catalog in each of the store which is getting the new rewrite, are there any other checks I should make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER 1:  var_dump($observer) is a good start
but this will allow me to retrieve the data in preparation for replication:

$request = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getPost();